# Controller routing not working as expected in silverstripe 3.1

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm setting up routing to a controller and I keep getting either a 404, or the 'getting started with the silverstripe framework' page.

In routes.yaml I have:

```
---
Name: nzoaroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'view-meetings/$Action/$type': 'ViewMeeting_Controller'
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class ViewMeeting_Controller extends Controller {

  public static $allowed_actions = array('HospitalMeetings');

  public static $url_handlers = array(
        'view-meetings/$Action/$ID' => 'HospitalMeetings'
    );

  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    if(!Member::currentUser()) {
      return $this->httpError(403);
    }
  }

  /* View a list of Hospital meetings of a specified type for this user */
  public function HospitalMeetings(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

    print_r($arguments, 1);

  }
}
```

And I've created a template (ViewMeeting.ss) that simply outputs $Content, but when I flush the site cache and visit /view-meetings/HospitalMeetings/6?flush=1

I get the default 'getting started with the Silverstripe framework' page

I know the routing in routes.yaml is working, because if I change the route there and visit the old URL I get a 404, but the request doesn't seem to fire my $Action...

Answer (score 2):

You had 2 different rules in your YAML and controller ($type vs $ID). Also, I don't think you need to define the route in both YAML and the Controller.

Try this, the YAML tell SS to send everything that starts with 'view-meetings' to your Controller, then `$url_handlers` tell the Controller what to do with the request depending on everything after 'view-meetings' in the URL.

routes.yaml

```
---
Name: nzoaroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'view-meetings': 'ViewMeeting_Controller'
```

ViewMeeting_Controller.php

```
class ViewMeeting_Controller extends Controller {

  private static $allowed_actions = array('HospitalMeetings');

  public static $url_handlers = array(
      '$Action/$type' => 'HospitalMeetings'
  );

  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    if(!Member::currentUser()) {
      return $this->httpError(403);
    }
  }

  public function HospitalMeetings(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Silverstripe documentation on routing isn't at all clear on this point, but for `$Action` to be correctly interpreted you should use a double slash before it in the `routes.yml` file:

`view-meetings//$Action/$type`

According to [the documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/controller#url-patterns), this sets something called the 'shift point'. Exactly what this means isn't described very well either in the documentation or in the [source code](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/control/HTTPRequest.php#L435) which matches URLs against rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing some guessing here, but what if you drop the

```
public static $url_handlers = array(
    'view-meetings/$Action/$ID' => 'HospitalMeetings'
);
```

part and change the Action method to:

```
// View a list of Hospital meetings of a specified type for this
public function HospitalMeetings(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

// Should print 8 if url is /view-meetings/HospitalMeetings/6
print_r($request->param('type');
```

}